# C++ FILE to fstream?

Tags: c++, file

I'm not an expert on this but I have this code:

```
FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;

OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &keys );

fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
```

And I would like to pass it to a fstream syntax

like

```
ofstream fs;
```

????

They are included on this function:

```
int Store(int keys, char *file)
```

I know this is a C function but since I'm learning C++ I would like to know how do I translate this to a C++

sorry I don't know what else or if fs is compatible to fopen.

More information:

Thanks everybody but it seems its ignoring some values

```
    int Store(int keys, char *file)
    {


    ofstream output_file("log.txt");
    output_file << keys; 
    output_file.close();

    cout << keys;

    return 0;
    }
```

when it oututs the file i just see a D i can see the hexadecimal values of the keys on the console but not being printed on the text....

Comment: Sorry I asked this kind of stuff before on this website

Comment: @Leandro: Because this site isn't for programming questions. Stack Overflow is.

Comment: @Leandro : If `keys` is an `int`, then the statement `fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &keys );` is completely nonsensical. What is the behavior you want from this?

Comment: @ildjarn: That statement almost looks like an attempt to serialize the integer `keys` by writing its constituent bytes, hoping that none of them are zero and that the memory afterwards is zero...

Comment: @Kerrek : Agreed that that looks like the desired behavior, I just figured I'd clarify before writing an answer since it's clearly broken. :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, ALL_CAPS should generally be reserved for macros -- using it for a normal variable holding a `FILE *` is generally a poor idea.

As far as the rest goes, it would look something like this:

```
std::fstream output_file(file, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
output_file << keys;
```

That could be a bit wrong, though -- right now your function prototype says `keys` is an `int`, but you're passing it to `fprintf` using the `%s` format, which is for a string, not an `int`. As-is, the code produces undefined behavior, and it's not *completely* certain what you really want. I've taken a guess I think is reasonable, but I'm not quite sure.

Edit: In case you're trying to write out the raw bytes of `keys`, that would look something like:

```
output_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&keys), sizeof(keys));
```

Thanks for the suggestion @ildjarn.

Comment: Show how to do unformatted output as well in case that's what he wants, and you're covered. :-]

Comment: Thank you i was paasing some int values from the main function to be output as strings on text file.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/

It is important to note that you can use the same C style writing in C++. So all of your C code will work in C++! Which is often time the happier solution, especially for IO that doesn't need to be lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

To use ofstream:

```
std::ofstream foo; //Declaring the ofstream object
foo.open("file_name"); //Setting the output file name
foo<<keys; //Now it's ready to take << input!
foo.close(); //When you're done with the file
```